# Vista OS disk for Gateway used to install on another Laptop

Tags: windows, windows-vista, installation, media, legal

Is it possible to use a Vista OS cd for a Gateway laptop to install Vista on another Laptop? I wish to do this since the other Laptop didn't come with an OS cd, and recently I had to completely replace the corrupted Vista with Ubuntu I now need to reinstall Vista but only have my Vista disk for my Gateway laptop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe. If you have the Vista key for this computer in particular, a OS install should be possible for any type of CD. You´ve to try it to know for sure if yours CD works. I sucessfully installed with OEM install cd´s in diferent computers (Dell Notebook, Dell Workstation, HP). But none were Vista. The last one was XP SP2.

--
*Portuguese Version/Versão em Português:*
Talvez. Se você tiver a chave de registro do Vista para este computador em particular, a instalação do S.O. deveria ser possível para qualquer tipo de CD. Você tem que tentar a instalação para ter certeza. Eu instalei com sucesso usando cd´s de instalação OEM em diferentes computadores (Notebook Dell, Estação de Trabalho Dell, Notebook HP). Mas nenhum deles era Vista. O último era XP SP2.

Comment: This would be awesome if I was proved wrong. I have never had luck and have tried before and I have not heard of many success stories. It is worth a try OP, go for it and report back on your success/failure.

Answer (score 2):

No, most OEM install cd's are made only for that specific computer model and will only work with that computer.

Answer (score 0):

The freedom to install one OS on many PCs ended with windows 2k. XP onward is Microsux's attempt to get paid for every PC in the house. I have installed 2k on all of my home PCs numerous times.I'll switch to linux before upgrading.