# Installing Windows Vista without system restore CD with OEM key (ie: from underside of my laptop)

Tags: windows-vista, restore, license-key

I have a family friend who needs to reformat her laptop (virus infected). She has misplaced her system restore disk. The laptop is running Vista, and has a valid Vista product key on a sticked on the underside of the laptop.

What are my options for installing Vista on this laptop without the system restore CD?

Can I use any Windows Vista CD to install the OS on this laptop as long as I use the key that came with the laptop?

This question seems related to [question 18213](https://superuser.com/questions/18213/vista-os-disk-for-gateway-used-to-install-on-another-laptop), which asks whether it's possible to use the OS disk and key shipped with one machine to install Vista on a different machine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it should work.  Your install will go into OEM mode.  You should also check to see if the laptop has a recovery partition on the HD already.  This blog post has [a description of the process](http://blog.insanegenius.com/2008/04/installing-vista-sp1-with-oem-key.html).

Answer (score 3):

The Vista DVD includes all the Vista editions, so you can perform a clean install with any Vista DVD.

When you see this screen, do not enter your product key, just press **Next**.

[image: Product Key]

Then select the edition of Vista that matches the once included with your laptop.

[image: Select Edition]

Paul Thurrott has a good article on [how to do a clean install](http://www.winsupersite.com/showcase/winvista_install_03.asp).

**Note:** Before you reinstall Vista, download any required drivers for the laptop.  You should be able to find them on the manufacturers website.